# nginx unknown directive ssl_protocols

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl

I've compiled NGINX 1.4.1 with ssl support and wanted to secure my configuation with these lines:

```
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_protocols        SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers          AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256;
ssl_session_cache       shared:TLSSL:16m;
ssl_session_timeout     10m;
```

This is the error I'm getting which I don't understand why it comes up:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "ssl_protocols        SSLv3"
```

my nginx configuration:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.4.1
built by gcc 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-http_dav_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-    http_stub_status_module --prefix=/opt/nginx --with-http_perl_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-perl=/usr/bin/perl --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_realip_module
```

maybe anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: maybe its the SSLv3?

Comment: Could you post more of your nginx config? Where are you calling the ssl_* settings?

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that SSL is not enabled by default. Did you add the `--with-http_ssl_module` flag when building? It requires openssl.

Comment: yeah, nginx -V gives me "--with-http_ssl_module"

Answer (score 2):

For security reason SSLv3 is disabled by default even if you invoke SSL module.

Here is the tracking information and you can find also the fix if you really want to use SSLv3:
https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/653